# Dell Inspiron Failed Bios Test - Next Steps

Tags: hard-drive, bios, dell-inspiron

I have Inspiron 15R 5521 (purchased in 2013) that won't start up. When I ran BIOS test I got

Error Code: 2000-0142

Validation: 111399

Msg: Hard Drive 0

Before I call Tech Support, what can I do on my own?

I never opened up a computer to see hardware components, but I can do this with guidance. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code is Hard Drive failed during diagnostic.

I have added the needed text. In the link you can also jump to solution.  But all is below here.

https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Hard-Drive-Failed-during-diagnostic-Error-Code-2000-0142/td-p/4010351

> A PSA/ePSA diagnostic code of 2000-0142 indicates the the HDD (hard
> disk drive) Self Test was unsuccessful. It could be the HDD, HDD
> cable, or connector on the motherboard. Open the system, reseat the
> HDD and HDD cable. Run the PSA/ePSA test again. If you get the same
> error, if the system is under warranty, we will replace the HDD. If
> the system is out of warranty, post the model and someone can
> recommend a possible replacement for your faulty HDD.

If you need to try to access the drive, you can try to start with a bootable USB key to see if you can see the drive.  You can also remove the drive and put in a USB carrier and plug that into a working computer.

Comment: What size Phillips screw driver should I get. The ones at home are too big (and I'm afraid they might have worn out the screw threads with my attempts)

Comment: You need a number 0 Philips (maybe number 1) Check Home Depot